# truststore works even with wrong password, why?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat7, tomcat6

I just set my tomcat webapp to support SSL
using this like as a guide:
[SSL Configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration)

I was told there to add this to server.xml:

```
"<Connector 
 port="8443" maxThreads="200"
 scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
 keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" **keystorePass="changeit"**
 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Now, the SSL works fine, but when I want to enter to webservice i have through another program that uses mytruststore.jks, it possible even with wrong mytruststore password.

for being more clear,
-I must use this "mytruststore.jks" to enter to the webservice
-"mytruststore.jks" password does not being checked by the tomcat server

Does this situation related to **keystorePass** used in server.xml?
When I remove the "keystorePass" Tomcat not working.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please clarify whether you're talking about the keystore password (actual question) or the truststore password (title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use the keystorePass to provide some level of authentication security to a SSL secured website.  This is not the way that SSL works, you are securing the data being transmitted between web server and the client browser.  It won't block access to a site.

The keystorePass specifies the password to unencrypt the .jks file using something like keytool.

I may be way off, but this is how I interpret the situation, please update with what you expect to happen.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'this is not the way SSL works'. Authentication is a critical part of SSL, and in Java it is provided by keystores, with passwords, and truststores. This is *exactly* the way SSL works. -1

Comment: @EJP The way Rosh puts it sounds legit to me: SSL does not rely on the keystore password to be present anywhere else but on the server, where the keystore is decrypted with said password. The authentication that SSL/TLS provides is that the client can be reasonably be sure to talk to the correct server, if it presents the correct certificate. The whole trust/encryption/authentication stuff in SSL/TLS is a recipe for lots of misunderstandings, but to me it sounds like Rosh got it right here. +1. I can't see anything that contradicts your answer to this question

Comment: @OlafKock, the keystorePass (in the Tomcat connector) is used by Tomcat to unlock and use the private key: it's necessary to get it right on the server side (on which this Connector config sample is). When a keystore is used as a trust store (on the client side), EJP's answer is correct. The question is a bit unclear, but this answer doesn't quite make sense. keystorePass is definitely not just for keytool.

Answer (score 1):

When using a keystore file as a truststore, the password is only used for verification, and errors in verification may well be entirely ignored. The password is really only there to protect private keys, and there aren't any in a truststore.